# ResultSet returns only the last record from the table

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

The below java method sets the ResultSet data to a bean class and I am fetching the data. But, the method runHiveQuery() returns only one row that is the last record in the table. While debugging the code i found that the resultset is being looped twice as we have two records. But, while returning the bean class object there is some issue as it retrieves only one record.

Unable to find what is going wrong.

```
public CSPData getCSPData() throws SQLException {
        try {
            String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
            Class.forName(drivername);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hddev-c01-edge-01:20000/");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultset = statement.executeQuery(
                    "select distinct db_name as db_name,db_server_name as db_server_name,lower(db_name) as l_db_name,lower(db_server_name) as l_server_name,regexp_replace(lower(db_server_name), '-', '_') as server_name,db_server_name_secondary as db_server_name_secondary from csp.curated_input");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        while (resultset.next()) {
            cspdata.setDbName(resultset.getString("db_name"));
            cspdata.setDbServerName(resultset.getString("db_server_name"));
            cspdata.setDbServerNameSecondary(resultset.getString("db_server_name_secondary"));
            cspdata.setlDbName(resultset.getString("l_db_name"));
            cspdata.setlServerName(resultset.getString("l_server_name"));
            cspdata.setServerName(resultset.getString("server_name"));
        }

        return cspdata;
    }

public void runHiveQuery() throws SQLException {

        CSPData cspdata = hivedao.getCSPData();
        String hive_db = "csp";
        String dbname = cspdata.getDbName();
        String dbservername = cspdata.getDbServerName();
        String servername = cspdata.getlServerName();

        String drop = "Drop table if exists " + hive_db + "." + "IB_C3_" + dbname + "_" + dbservername;
        String insert = "insert into table " + hive_db + "." + "IB_export_log select " + "\'ib_c3_" + dbname + "_"
                + servername + "\' from " + hive_db + "." + "dual limit 1";

        System.out.println(drop);
        System.out.println(insert);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns the last record since it only returns a single record. You should return a List :

```
public List<CSPData> getCSPData() throws SQLException {
    List<CSPData> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        String drivername = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
        Class.forName(drivername);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hddev-c01-edge-01:20000/");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(
                "select distinct db_name as db_name,db_server_name as db_server_name,lower(db_name) as l_db_name,lower(db_server_name) as l_server_name,regexp_replace(lower(db_server_name), '-', '_') as server_name,db_server_name_secondary as db_server_name_secondary from csp.curated_input");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    while (resultset.next()) {
        CSPData cspdata = new CSPData ();
        cspdata.setDbName(resultset.getString("db_name"));
        cspdata.setDbServerName(resultset.getString("db_server_name"));
        cspdata.setDbServerNameSecondary(resultset.getString("db_server_name_secondary"));
        cspdata.setlDbName(resultset.getString("l_db_name"));
        cspdata.setlServerName(resultset.getString("l_server_name"));
        cspdata.setServerName(resultset.getString("server_name"));
        result.add(cspdata);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eran, like you mentioned i have created an arraylist and added the records but now it returns the same record twice. Please suggest.

Comment: @dataEnthusiast did you notice the `CSPData cspdata = new CSPData ();` statement inside the while loop?